# Understanding why async function doesn't finish

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I'm trying to use Google Drive API. I saw in a tutorial how to access it and how to read files. I'm creating a simple Desktop app with .NET Maui but I have a problem understanding what is happening with the function I use to access the Google Drive.

```cs
public partial class MainPageViewModel: ObservableObject
{
    public ObservableCollection<Models.File> DriveFileInfo { get; set; }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        DriveFileInfo = new ObservableCollection<Models.File>();
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task Populate()
    {
        await Initialize();
    }

    private async Task Initialize()
    {
        // Credential storage location
        string PathToCredentials = @"\credentials.json";
        var tokenStorage = new FileDataStore("UserCredentialStoragePath", true);

        UserCredential credential;
        await using (var stream = new FileStream(PathToCredentials, FileMode.Open,
            FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // Requesting Authentication or loading previously stored
            // authentication for userName
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.FromStream(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { DriveService.ScopeConstants.DriveReadonly },
                    "userName",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    tokenStorage)
                .Result;
        }

        // Create the  Drive service.
        var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });

        var request = service.Files.List();
        request.PageSize = 1000;
        request.Q = "parents in '1bbZTzmYtlxFTA06JJvAE-tojIAoOHETM'";
        var results = await request.ExecuteAsync();

        DriveFileInfo = new ObservableCollection<Models.File>();
        foreach (var driveFile in results.Files)
        {
            DriveFileInfo.Add(new Models.File(driveFile.Name.ToString(),
                driveFile.MimeType.ToString(), driveFile.Id.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

My problem might be the incorrect understanding of async methods but I thought that since I have an `async` method and a `await`, my Button would wait for the `Initialize()` method to finish.

What is happening is that when I start my debugger, the program runs until this line:

```cs
var tokenStorage = new FileDataStore("UserCredentialStoragePath", true);
```

Then, the method ends and the program moves forward not finishing the `Initialize()` method.

Could you help me understand what is happening?

Comment: `.Result` is always a ref flag; can you try `credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(...etc...);` ? you might be deadlocking

Comment: Google upgraded to OAUTH2 authentication.  See : https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng: This code *is* using OAuth2.

Comment: I strongly suspect the problem is indeed the use of `Result`. Awaiting the credential task should fix it. Note that you can use `GoogleClientSecrets.FromFile` rather than creating a `FileStream`, which will make the code simpler too.

Comment: After removing Resut and changing the credentials path it worked, thank you! One thing that is happening is: ```string PathToCredentials = @"credentials.json"; ```This path is being recognized as```C:\Windows\System32\credetials.json``` should it be the path to the program folder?

Comment: Do you understand what `.Result` means and why you should almost never use it in an asynchronous workflow?  "await" means "do something else while you're waiting".  "Result" means "do nothing while you're waiting".  Now, suppose the *thread that computes the result* is the thread that you just told to "do nothing". What do you think happens?